# Ubuntu: Display SOH character in Terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, character-encoding, special-characters

When using the terminal with Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, the `SOH` character is not being displayed when outputted from a program.

The same program also successfully prints the output to a file which correctly displays these `SOH` characters, as seen below as the 4 square characters containing "0001" towards the right of the output.

[image: A screenshot of the file output with delimiter characters which are not shown in the terminal.]

The same output (excluding the timestamp on the left) can be seen below taken from the terminal, but **without** the required symbols which should separate the `tag=value` pairs:

[image: Terminal output without any delimiters to separate values.]

**Question:** How can the terminal display the output including the SOH character as seen in the first image? This worked correctly on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS automatically, but doesn't seem to have worked on 20.04.1.

Ideally, the **terminal output** would look like this:

```
8=FIX.4.2|9=84|35=A|43=1|
```

**Attempts:**
I thought that maybe the terminal encoding could be the issue, so I attempted `export LANG=$LANG.UTF-8` and then reopened the terminal which I found at the following SO question, to no success:

**Note:** I have no issue typing this character in the terminal- I'm just having trouble getting it to print as an output.

Comment: I'm not sure the terminal emulator can do that for you. However, using `cat -v` or viewing the files in `less` will give the `^A` notation for SOH.

Comment: That is a (mis)feature of the terminal (since the character is known to be non-printing), probably with the help of the underlying libraries (e.g., pango).  The relevant developers may recall which bug report fixed this.